# Click a link in IE through VBA

Tags: html, excel, vba

I am trying to click a link but it is different from others links I have made it. I don't have a field called "id" or something.

Here is the HTML. I need it to click "pibmunic super" button/link. The FIREPATH XPath shows **.//*[@id='informacoes_estatisticas']/ul/li[20]/span**

```
<div id="informacoes_estatisticas">
<h3 class="titulo">Informações Estatísticas</h3>
<ul class="links">
<li class="item Censo Agropecuário_2006">
<li class="censo2010 super">
<li class="educa super">
<li class="empresas super">
<li class="vida super">
<li class="item Estimativa da População 2014_">
<li class="prodext2013 super">
<li class="financas super">
<li class="frota super">
<li class="item Fundações Privadas e Associações sem Fins Lucrativos no Brasil 2010_">
<li class="item Índice de Desenvolvimento Humano Municipal - IDHM_">
<li class="instfin super">
<li class="item Mapa de Pobreza e Desigualdade - Municípios Brasileiros_2003">
<li class="morbid super">
<li class="prodpec2013 super">
<li class="item Pesquisa Nacional de Saneamento Básico_2008">
<li class="item Produção Agrícola Municipal - Cereais, Leguminosas e Oleaginosas_2007">
<li class="lavperm2013 super">
<li class="lavtemp2013 super">
<li class="pibmunic super">
    <span class="super">Produto Interno Bruto dos Municípios</span>
    <ul class="pibmunic sub">
</li>
<li class="partpol super">
<li class="assismed super">
<li class="snig_censo2010 super">
</ul>
</div>
```

I am trying to write my code as something like this

```
Set m = html.getElementById("something")
Set a = m.getElementsByTagName("something")(something)
a.Click
```

I am not sure this is right, I have tried lots of combinations and it does not work. I don't know exactly which "getelementsby" I should use or what to give the command inside ().

Hope you can help me !! thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All of your classes seem to be unique.  If that's the case you should change all the `class` attributes to `id` attributes ex:

```
class="something"
```

to

```
id="something"
```

Once you do that `getElementById("something")` will work.  `getElementsByTagName()` returns an array of elements with a specific tag. ex:

```
getElementsByTagName("li")
```

retrieves all the `li` elements under a node.

If the newest VBA supports `querySelectorAll()` that will allow you to use CSS selectors to find elements.  ex:

```
querySelectorAll(".something")
```

This will find all elements with the class `something`.  However, since there can be multiple elements with the same class, you will get an *array* as a result.  You can either loop over these elements to process them, narrow your selector, or get the first index of the returned array.

If VBA still does not support `querySeletorAll()` and you will need to combine `getElementsByTagName()` with a loop over the matching tags to find elements with the `something` class.  ex:

```
For Each el in getElementById("container").getElementsByTagName("li")
    For Each cl in el.className.Split(' ')
        If cl = "something" Then
            el.onclick()
        End If
    Next 
Next
```

I would recommend assigning Id's or *if at all possible* use JavaScript or jQuery.  They are more specialized at handling at these tasks (more abstraction).  jQuery would be as simple as:

```
$(".something").trigger("click");
```